# Embed Python in Visual C++

Tags: python, c++, debugging

I tried to embed Python in Visual C++ using Visual Studio 2019. I found some code on the web, did some copycat and executed the program. I don't know how to fix the problem:

> Exception thrown read access violation, m was nullptr.

I have searched all over the web, no one answered this question.

[image]

This is the python code:

```
'''py_function.py - Python source designed to '''
'''demonstrate the use of python embedding'''

def multiply():
    c = 12345*6789
    print 'The result of 12345 x 6789 :', c
    return c
```

Comment: You don't check anywhere whether your `Py(DoSomething)` operation succeeds. One of them fails, likely the import. I think you should use `"py_function"` without `.py`, but that's just a guess. Other possibility is invalid paths. Anyway, inspect the error.

Comment: I have tried simply 'py_function', it didn't work. I have also tried to type the full path.

Comment: pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char* )"py_function");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

pyDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pyDict, (char*) "multipy");

This is the first trial.